# Raspberry PI wifi signal transmission via UDP or TCPIP is inconsistent

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, wifi

I have an application where I am sending a on/off signal from one raspberry pi (Pi zero) via TCP/IP (or UDP) over wifi to another Raspberry pi (PI4). I need this transmission to be lag free as much as possible. I have tried using tcp/ip and the UDP protocols but in both cases I see inconsistent delays in receipt of data. The wifi is being generated locally with a dedicated wifi router and only two devices on the network are the Pis. Here is the section of the code on the Pi zero that sends the signal:

```
s=socket.socket()
port=12397
s.bind(('',port))
s.listen(5)
i=0
while runserver:
    try:
        c,addr = s.accept()
        print("Client connected")
        while True:
            if i==1:
                i=0
            else:
                i=1
            c.send(str(i))
            time.sleep(1) #Sleep for 1 second
        c.close()
    except:
        print("Client disconnected")
```

Here is the code that is running on the Pi 4 that receives the signal:

```
host = '192.168.43.2'
port = 12397
runclient = 1
while runclient:
    try:
        s = socket.socket()
        #This is to ensure that if the server disconnects for any reason
        #the signal being sent out is reset to 2 (unknown)
        s.settimeout(5.0)
        s.connect((host,port))
        try:
            while True:
                try:
                    flag.value = int(s.recv(1))
                except socket.timeout:
                    flag.value = int(2)
                    print("Server disconnected")
                    break
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
            s.close()
        #except socket.error as e:
        #    print(e.args[0])
        #    continue
    except:
        print("No Server", end='\r')
        flag.value = int(2)
```

As you can see from the Pi Zero code, I am flipping the values between 1 and 0 every 1 second. What I expect to see on the Pi4 side is the received values following the same trend every 1 second. But what I end up seeing is that the time gap between signal changes vary between 0.2 to 1.5 and some times 2.5 seconds. I have tried to bring the router as close as possible to both the Pis (Both the Pis are within 4 feet of each other).

Does anyone have any ideas on why there is this delay in the receiving side? Is it the wifi buffering? What can be done to improve this situation?

Comment: Try setting the `TCP_NODELAY` socket option to disable the Nagle algorithm.

Comment: Based on your suggestion I have tried this, see the update below.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to initiate the socket as

`s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)`
`s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)`

I did see an improvement with buffering but the buffering artefact that I see in the incoming data trace is still there (although much less frequent). So I am looking now at what I might need to do at the wifi router level to improve this.

There is more information here:
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/tcp-ip-options-for-high-performance-data-transmission/